# How to calculate precision and recall using Confusion Matrix

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, tensorboard

[Confusion matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLg0o.jpg)
we know that the precision formula is tp/(tp+fp) and the recall formula is tp/(tp+fn) my doubt is how to get tp, fp, fn values from the confusion matrix and what is predicted on the y-axis side and what is true on x-axis side of the given confusion matrix.

from the confusion matrix. I want tp, tn, fp, fn, and what is true on the x-axis and predicated on the y-axis and what are background fp and background fn.
How to read tp, tn, fp, fn from the given confusion matrix above image.

Answer (score 0):

True Positive are the predicted output that are actually correct and predicted correct.

True Negative are the predicted output that are actually incorrect and predicted incorrect.

False Positive are the predicted output that are actually incorrect and predicted correct.

False Negative are the predicted output that are actually correct and predicted incorrect.

you can go throught this medium article they have elplained it for multiclass classification you can easily understand this.
[Multi-Class Metrics Precision, Recall](https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-class-metrics-made-simple-part-i-precision-and-recall-9250280bddc2)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

confusion matrix for multi class is :

main diameter is **TP**

TP the predicted output that are actually correct and predicted correct.

TN are the predicted output that are actually incorrect and predicted incorrect.

FP are the predicted output that are actually incorrect and predicted correct.

FP are the predicted output that are actually correct and predicted incorrect.

[image]

you can use this [link](https://towardsai.net/p/l/multi-class-model-evaluation-with-confusion-matrix-and-classification-report)
or this [link](https://www.mariakhalusova.com/posts/2019-04-17-ml-model-evaluation-metrics-p2/)